# Can soot perform program analysis for incomplete code

Tags: java, javaparser, soot, wala

What I understand is [Soot](https://github.com/soot-oss/soot) performs program analysis on the ByteCode.

However, I have incomplete or slightly buggy-code like the following where the return type for the method is not correct:

```
class D {

    public void m1() {
        int total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            total += i;
        }
        return total;
    }

}
```

Will Soot be able to do program analysis on partially complete code or slightly buggy code?

Comment: From what I know Soot expects valid Java 7 code.

Comment: @JMax so it does not support > Java 8 versions?

Comment: As far as I know not. The source code parsing module of Soot is unmaintained since Java 7 was the most recent Java version.